# Field Required for Customers extends to Vendors, etc

Tags: acumatica

I created a custom field called Certification Type on the Manage Customers page and set it as required by marking it [PXDefault] in the data access class.  The problem is that it becomes required for all screens that use the BAAccount class, Vendors, Employees and Contacts.  Is there a way to make the field required for Customers, but not Vendors, Employess or Contacts?

Answer (score 3):

You can override the extension field by screen by extending the graph of each screen where you need to disable the PXDefault attribute.

```
public class VendorMaintExt : PXGraphExtension<VendorMaint>
{
    [PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Merge)]
    [PXDefault(PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]    
    protected virtual void BAccount_CertificationType_CacheAttached(PXCache sender)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is two ways I can think of initially to do what you want.

1) Move the custom field from the BAcct DAC to the Customer DAC.  "Customers" contains fields from BAcct as well as the secondary "Customers" table.  This way you can leave the [PXDefault] attribute

2) Remove the [PXDefault] attribute from the DAC and add it to an extension class of CustomerMaint using the cache attached event:

Something like this

```
[PXDefault]
{rest of your field attributes]
protected virtual void BAcct_{yourfield}_CacheAttached(PXCache sender)
{
}
```

Doing that will make the field required on the customer maintenance screen but optional everywhere else.   Make sure your field allows null values from the database side.

Note: in 5.0+ you do not need to redefine all of the values, instead you could use the following attribute

```
[PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Merge)]
```

Comment: Jeff  I tried     [PXDBString(255)]
                     [PXDefault]
                    [PXUIField(DisplayName="CertificationType",                       Required=true)]
                     [PXStringList(new string[] { "EMail", "Paper", "Both", "None" },
                      new string[] { "Email", "Paper", "Both", "None" }, MultiSelect = false)]
protected virtual void     Customer_UsrCertType_CacheAttached(PXCache sender)
{
}

Comment: but it produced the error  Failed to subscribe event PX.Objects.AR.CustomerMaint_Extension::BAccount_UsrCertType_CacheAttached in graph PX.Objects.AR.CustomerMaint. 
Method signature looks like event handler, 
but cache BAccount has not been found in the list of auto initialized caches. 
Remove unused event handlers from code.

Comment: In The above code change protected virtual void to BAccount_UsrCertType ...  I keep hitting enter for a carriage return and it posts before I want it to and then my edit time exceeds five minutes,  sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answers:

A mandatory field is marked by an asterisk (*) on the form to cue the reader that a value must be specified for it.
To mark a control for a mandatory field with an asterisk, you should set the Required property of the PXUIField attribute to true.

[PXCustomizeBaseAttribute(typeof(PXUIFieldAttribute), "Required", true)]